# Check exactly one boolean option set

Tags: javascript, node.js

Well, this is kind of hacky:

```
function b2n(boo) {
    return boo ? 1 : 0;
}

if(b2n(opt1) + b2n(opt2) + b2n(opt3) !== 1) {
    throw new Error("Exactly one option must be set");
}
```

Is there a better way to do this in Javascript?  Using any of

- more intelligent boolean/number handling
- sneaky array or functional operations

And so forth.  Javascript and Node solutions welcome.

In my actual problem, the options are coming from the Node module commander, so I'm not dealing with true boolean, just truthy and falsy things. There may be a commander-solution too.

Comment: What's the use case you are solving for? Are you validating user input?  If so, can you use radio buttons?

Comment: @ChadCook this is server side. It's commanding from `node.js` commander.  In my actual problem it defaults to `opt3` so I actually check for `> 1`.

Comment: How are you running Javascript server-side?

Comment: @ChadCook [tag:node.js]

Comment: (true + false === 1). Boolean automaticaly will be converted to int

Comment: @DmitryTeplyakov yes, needed to make sure values are boolean too using `!!`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you had an array of options, you could do:

```
if(opts.filter(Boolean).length !== 1) {}
```

It seems to me though that you ought to have one variable with three possible states instead...

```
var opt = 'a'; // (or 'b', or 'c')
```

Comment: Why even bother passing an anonymous function? Just use `if (opts.filter(Boolean).length !== 1) {}`. Or even with your anonymous function, it makes more sense to just return `v`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to just use the Boolean function. Hadn't thought of that, and it it's a big improvement. As far as just returning v, I coded it like that initially but changed it because the asker was not certain that the values would actually be booleans in the first place.

Comment: No problem! And yeah, if it's something simple like this, I try and think of a way to pass a built-in function instead of a custom one. Well for returning `v`, it works - the value returned from the callback passed to `filter` is evaluated as **truthy**, not `true`, so it doesn't matter if the contents are booleans. So for example, if you just `return v;`, `""` will not pass, while `"a"` will. Using `Boolean` technically does the same thing, just sooner

Comment: Brilliant, @spudly! I wish I had thought of that.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this :

```
if ( !!opt1 + !!opt2 + !!opt3 !== 1 ) {
```

It works because

- `!!` makes a boolean from any value (`true` if the objects evaluates as `true` in `if(value)`)
- when adding booleans you get `1` for `true` and `0` for `false`.

Comment: If he knows they're boolean, the !! is unnecessary, so you could change that to if (opt1 + opt2 + opt3 != 1) {}

Comment: @spudly I don't know if the values are boolean. This wasn't clear in the question.

Comment: They're not actually, in any case this is the safest way to go.

Comment: Less readable, but you could simplify the expression to: `!opt1 + !opt2 + !opt3 === 2` (2 is the number of options, 3, minus the one truthy option).

Comment: @Paulpro yes, that's true, but I don't think it's worth it. The semantic gap with the goal is too wide in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are being too clever, what's wrong with:

```
var optionsSelected = 0;
if( opt1 ) optionsSelected++;
if( opt2 ) optionsSelected++;
if( opt3 ) optionsSelected++;

if( optionsSelected !== 1 ) {
    throw new Error("Exactly one option must be set");
}
```

Of course I can play the clever game too:

```
 if( opts.filter(Boolean).length !== 1 ) {
     throw new Error("Exactly one option must be set");
 }
```

Comment: Javascript has a lot of well-accepted patterns that let you do in a readable one line of code what would take 8.  I prefer "clever" patterns when they're well-understood (and hence not clever).  I'm fairly novice in Javascript hence don't know these yet.

Comment: For examples of "clever" solutions, see every other answer.

Comment: Should have given the clever one before, people are fickle.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned in your comment that this is coming from a commander options object.

You can do this more elegantly using [Lodash](http://lodash.com/):

```
if (_(options).values().compact().size() === 1)
```

If you only want to count a subset of the options, you can insert

```
.pick('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Comment: Ah, that's how you use lodash fluently.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ([opt1, opt2, opt3].reduce(function(x, y) { return x + !!y }, 0) == 1) {
    // exactly one
};
```

ECMAScript 5 [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function.

Answer (score 0):

@spudly is on the right track, but it could be a little more compact:

```
if( [opt1,opt2,opt3].filter(function(x){return x}).length!==1 ) {
    throw new Error("Exactly one option must be set");
}
```

See [ES5's filter method](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.20) for more information.